# Firebase - Order child value from low to high

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order my tableView with values from Firebase from low to high. This is what I got so far:

```
     Database.database().reference().child("Bier").queryOrdered(byChild: "Voor_prijs_int").queryStarting(atValue: 0).queryEnding(atValue: 10000).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        print("test")
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            print("test2")
            for snap in snapshots {
               print("test3")
               if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                   print("test4")
                   let key = snap.key
                   let bier = BierModel.transformbier(dict: postDict, key: key)
                   self.bier_model.insert(bier, at: 0)
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

When I run this code it seems that it get stuck by `print("test2")`, because it never print

> test3

I am not sure why this is, because I have got this code from a other project that worked.

Here is my Firebase structure:

[image: Firebase structure]

Thanks

Comment: Did you search for the error message? I'm quite sure the question of how to get rid of that message has been answered before, so you can use search, or look at [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). If you did can't get that to work for you, show what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! I have fixed the `"indexOn."` console log, but it is still not working. If I print snapshots it's just empty. So that why it wont go 
further with `for snap in snapshots {` . That means it can't find anything with this reference, but I don't know why. I think it can't find `"Voor_prijs_int"` for some reason.

Comment: I don't see what's going wrong here. The code looks fine, and matches the JSON, as far as I can see. :-/

Comment: Strange... If I remove the `.queryOrdered(byChild: "Voor_prijs_int").queryStarting(atValue: 0).queryEnding(atValue: 10000)` everything seems to be fine. Is this maybe a bug or something?

Comment: If there was a bug in querying on numbers I'd expect it to have been reported many more times. So I'm wondering if you're hitting an edge case, or if we're just overlooking something. I hope somebody who has iOS/Swift ready to go can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

This code will sort the data based on the smallest value of variable to the largest:

```
      self.bier_model.sort { $0.variable < $1.variable }
```